# how to set cookie in nextjs 13.4.2 in api route

Tags: next.js

how to set cookie in nextjs 13.4.2

i have try with NextResponse and cookies-next, but its not set the cookie in my browser.

my flow is

- user sigin
- validate user
- save jwt in cookie http only

*app/api/signin/route.ts*

[image]

i want to set cookie if the user signin and save the jwt token in cookie storage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using the "Set-Cookie" headers in the NextResponse.

```
export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {
    // do stuff here

    return new NextResponse(<JSON body>, {
        status: 200,
        headers: { "Set-Cookie": `jwt=${jwt}; sameSite=strict; httpOnly=true; maxAge=60*60*24` },
    });
}
```

Responses with `Set-Cookie` headers will set the cookies.

Otherwise, if you would like to set the cookies using the NextReponse methods, create the response first then use set()

```
export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {
  const response = NextResponse.json(
    {data},
    { status: 200, statusText: "Set cookie successfully" }
  );

  response.cookies.set({
    name: "jwt",
    value: jwt,
    maxAge: 60*60*24,
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: strict,
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks its work with nextResponse and response. btw what diferent between nextresponse and response.

Comment: [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) is part of the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) that exists outside of NextJS ecosystem.

NextResponse is Nextjs's way of extending the API with additional methods such as .cookies(), .json() etc

You can take a look at the [NextResponse documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/next-response)

Comment: appreciated sir ❤️